# How to accept all connections in freeradius2?

Tags: freeradius2

I need to setup radius that accept any username/password and give some attrs for mpd.

Something like:  (raddb/users)

```
DEFAULT Framed-Protocol == PPP                                                                                    
    Service-Type = Framed-User,                                                                                   
    mpd-limit = "out#1=all shape 10240000 pass ",                                                                 
    mpd-limit += "in#1=all rate-limit 2048000 pass",                                                              
    Framed-Pool = "local"
```

I am not care about auth , username and other, because its backup radius, and its task accept all connections while we maintain "main" radiusd.

I tryed comment all in sites-available/default,

I tryed add DEFAULT Auth-Type = Accept

I tryed use Exec-Program-Wait = with program always return ok

But radius always return REJECT from mschap group, like that:

```
# Executing section authorize from file /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
+- entering group authorize {...}
++[chap] returns noop
[mschap] Found MS-CHAP attributes.  Setting 'Auth-Type  = mschap'
++[mschap] returns ok
[eap] No EAP-Message, not doing EAP
++[eap] returns noop
[files] users: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 208
++[files] returns ok
Found Auth-Type = MSCHAP
# Executing group from file /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
+- entering group MS-CHAP {...}
[mschap] No Cleartext-Password configured.  Cannot create LM-Password.
[mschap] No Cleartext-Password configured.  Cannot create NT-Password.
[mschap] Creating challenge hash with username: test
[mschap] Client is using MS-CHAPv2 for test, we need NT-Password
[mschap] FAILED: No NT/LM-Password.  Cannot perform authentication.
[mschap] FAILED: MS-CHAP2-Response is incorrect
++[mschap] returns reject
Failed to authenticate the user.
Login incorrect: [test] (from client localhost port 2 cli 00e05290b3e3 / 00:e0:52:90:b3:e3 / em1)
Using Post-Auth-Type REJECT
# Executing group from file /usr/local/etc/raddb/sites-enabled/default
+- entering group REJECT {...}
[attr_filter.access_reject]     expand: %{User-Name} -> test
attr_filter: Matched entry DEFAULT at line 11
++[attr_filter.access_reject] returns updated
Delaying reject of request 0 for 1 seconds
Going to the next request
Waking up in 0.9 seconds.
Sending delayed reject for request 0
Sending Access-Reject of id 175 to 127.0.0.1 port 64198
        MS-CHAP-Error = "\001E=691 R=1"
```

Help me please. How to set Accept for all username/pass ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `Auth-Type` attribute to accept the request:

```
DEFAULT Auth-Type := Accept
```

Comment: I tryed that. https://gist.github.com/3956774 Doesnt work

Comment: Oh, sorry. Its worked, i have problem not in radius but in mpd which want MS-CHAP2-Success. I add this, and now all works